# Get the time taken to enter console input in C#

Tags: c#, console, stopwatch

I have a method that takes an input from the console with `Console.ReadLine()`

I want to know how long the user has taken to write the input.

I know that I can record the time with the `StopWatch`, but I just want to record the time between the first key pressed and the enter key.

What could I do?

*Translated with google translator*

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  Some sort of 'how long did it take to enter a password' ?

Comment: Yes but its not a password

Comment: I want to get the average typing time per word.

Comment: I think you need to use [Console.ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Version 1**

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

// Read first key pressed, then start stopwatch
var firstChar = Console.ReadKey();
stopWatch.Start();

// Read the rest followed by enter, then stop stopwatch
var restOfString = Console.ReadLine();
stopWatch.Stop();

// Join first char and rest of string together
var wholeString = string.Concat(firstChar.KeyChar, restOfString);
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

Console.WriteLine($"String entered: {wholeString}.");
Console.WriteLine($"It took {ts.Seconds} seconds.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Version 2**

```
var keyInfo = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
var userInput = new StringBuilder();
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
var started = false;

do
{
     keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(false);

     if (started == false)
     {
          stopWatch.Start();
          started = true;
     }                

     switch (keyInfo.Key)
     {
          case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
              Console.Write(" \b");
              if(userInput.Length > 0) userInput.Remove(userInput.Length - 1, 1);
              break;
          // Stopping delete key outputting a space
          case ConsoleKey.Delete:
              Console.Write("\b");
              break;
          case ConsoleKey.Enter:
              break;
          default:
              userInput.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
              break;
    }
}
while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

var finalString = userInput.ToString();

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine($"String entered: {finalString}.");
Console.WriteLine($"It took {ts.Seconds} seconds.");

Console.ReadLine();
```

You might want to tidy up handling other special characters as this is just addressing your specific problem. Note also you can use `ReadKey(true)` instead to intercept the input and stop any output. You could then control your own output with `Console.Write()`.

**Version 3**

To give you options here is a version that does intercept and control the output. This would be my preference.

```
var keyInfo = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
var userInput = new StringBuilder();
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
var started = false;

do
{
    keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

    if (started == false)
    {
        stopWatch.Start();
        started = true;
    }

    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    {
        Console.Write("\b \b");
        if(userInput.Length > 0) userInput.Remove(userInput.Length - 1, 1);
    }
    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    else if(Char.IsLetter(keyInfo.KeyChar) ||
            Char.IsDigit(keyInfo.KeyChar) ||
            Char.IsWhiteSpace(keyInfo.KeyChar) ||
            Char.IsPunctuation(keyInfo.KeyChar))

    {
        Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
        userInput.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
    }
} while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

var finalString = userInput.ToString();

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine($"String entered: {finalString}.");
Console.WriteLine($"It took {ts.Seconds} seconds.");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The problem is that I cant delete the first char in the input

Comment: You don’t need to. Just imagine it is part of the main input string from ReadLine. I’ve split it out as a way to find when the first key press is.

Comment: But what if I want to delete the char while still writing my sentence?

Comment: Okay version 2 will do what you need.

Comment: And a version 3 showing out to intercept the output so you can control more easily which characters you output and add to string.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    Thread.Sleep(250);

var start = DateTime.Now;
var input = Console.ReadString();
var stop = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Do you mean `ReadLine()`?